# how do I make this a neat table

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, presentation

```
UNRAVEL_study %>%
  group_by(sleep_dep) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(unravel), SD=sd(unravel), min=min(unravel), max=max(unravel), IQR=IQR(unravel))
```

how do I get a presentable table that gives me the same info as this code chunk? im trig to do a presentation for class and we can't show any code

Comment: Can you specify what language is this?

Comment: its R markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I fixed it:

```
UNRAVEL_study %>%
  group_by(sleep_dep) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(unravel), SD=sd(unravel), min=min(unravel), max=max(unravel), IQR=IQR(unravel))%>%
   kable(., caption = "sleep deprivation descriptive statistics")
```

I used the Kable function which makes it into a really tidy table. Then up top I added the directions echo=FALSE to not include the code, and message=FALSE to not include the R console